# What is an effective word for not being attentive?

Tags: traduction, anglais

What is a good translation for not being attentive? Examples could be:

> Je n'étais pas [attentive] dans ma classe de Chimie

or

> Si tu n'étais pas [attentive] sur la rue, tu peux être dans un accident de voiture.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Être attentif* works just fine for your first example.

> Je n'étais pas attentif en [cours de] Chimie.

For your second example, [*faire attention*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/faire_attention) works better.

> Si tu ne fais pas attention dans la rue, tu risques d'avoir un accident [de voiture/vélo].

*Être attentif* implies attention to something in the sense of concentration, thought, attention to detail, etc. *Faire attention* is more in the sense of having to be careful, prudent.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use the word "distrait" which is the opposite of "attentif"

> J'étais distrait en cours de Chimie.

For the second example, you can use the word "vigilant" which is much stronger than "attentif".

> Si tu n'es pas vigilant sur la route, tu peux avoir un accident.